# Pipe netstat output multiple times

Tags: macos, bash, pipe, netstat

I want to store current network traffic [b/s] in Mac OS X into a file once a second.

```
netstat -b -n 1 |awk '{print $3}' |tail -n +3 >traffic.txt
```

*should* do want I want to - but the second pipe seems to be buffered, and I need the results as soon as possible.

If I only use one pipe, everything's fine, but I need at most these three.

`ulimit -p 0` doesn't work (not implemented?). Is there any other way to avoid buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` will buffer its output by default. Call `fflush()` to flush it.

```
netstat -b -n 1 |awk '{print $3;fflush()}' |tail -n +3 >traffic.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipes *are* buffers, and they will send along data when they get around to it. I don't know of a way to speed them along.

Also, did you mean `>> traffic.txt` at the end? Your solution would truncate, two angle brackets appends.